# What firewall rules and instance specs are needed to run a Flask app on google compute engine?

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to deploy a Flask web app on google compute engine and am wondering:

- What is the best instance type to use, is a `g1-small` sufficient?
- What network traffic do I allow for the instance, HTTP and HTTPS or just one of them?
- What port do I allow for the instance? I saw some people mentioned using `tcp 5000`.

Any other tips on instance or firewall specs would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

> What is the best instance type to use, is a g1-small sufficient?

The answer depends on the traffic workload for your instance. Start with micro or small, monitor response time and adjust instance size to match the load.

> What network traffic do I allow for the instance, HTTP and HTTPS or
>   just one of them?

That depends on what traffic/data you are serving. As a general rule, there is no reason to not implement HTTPS (SSL certificates) today.

> What port do I allow for the instance? I saw some people mentioned
>   using tcp 5000.

You should not be serving using Flask's development server, which defaults to port 5000. Instead use a production server. You'll need to open whatever port you configure your server to listen on.

Comment: I've been following the Flask tutorial for deploying the app to production via Waitress, but is there another way to do it besides `waitress-serve --call 'flaskr:create_app'`? I'm not sure what the `create_app` function should even look like for my app.